# Can not install nautilus-gksu in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, gksudo

I am trying to install `nautilus-gksu` in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by `sudo apt-get install nautilus-gksu` but I am having the following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nautilus-gksu
```

I also tried [How can I install nautilus-gksu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314267/how-can-i-install-nautilus-gksu) but It did not work. Is there a way to install it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gksu` is now deprecated.

I believe the proper way to open nautilus as root would be to use `sudo -i` instead.

Here's an example:

```
sudo -i nautilus &
```

Answer (score 1):

`nautilus-gksu` isn't a package for Ubuntu since 12.04. The binaries `gksu` and `gksudo` are in the package `gksu`.

Therefore install via

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```