# How to add files to /var/www/html/ without using the terminal?

Tags: apache2, files

Using Ubuntu 15

I install Apache and want to add files to the /var/www/html/ directory.

If I type in my browser: file:///var/www/html/  I can see the files (only index.html). However, I cannot add, remove or edit any file.

Is there any way I can access to /var/www/html/  without using the terminal, something similar to Windowns accessing through the Files functionality?

I read that I should be able to do it this way:
- Open Nautilus
- Goto Filesystem → var → www and now you can add/copy/paste your files.

But If I type in Nautilus, the File cabinet open up and I'm not able to locate Filesystem

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You have to run nautilus as root.

> gksu is now depreciated so
>
> I believe the proper way to open nautilus as root would be to use sudo
>   -i instead.
>
> Here's an example:
>
> `sudo -i nautilus &`
>
> [Can not install nautilus-gksu in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675745/can-not-install-nautilus-gksu-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: You could also use `pkexec natuilus` also

Answer (score 0):

Simply you don't have permission to write in the folder. Either you should use your file manager as root, or change the permission of the folder to 666